# How can I the process data from a singular column from a dataset brought in by a MySqlDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am using a MySqlDataAdapter to fill a dataGridView widget with data from my database like so

```
 using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT username AS `Opened By`, assignee_id AS `Assigned To`, ticket_category AS `Category`, ticket_summary AS `Summary`, ticket_description AS `Description`, ticket_status AS `Status` FROM tickets INNER JOIN users ON tickets.user_id = users.user_id;", connection);

            var dataset = new DataSet();

            adapter.Fill(dataset);

            ticketDataGrid.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0];
        }
```

ticket_status is a tinyint (boolean) that determines whether a ticket is open or closed. If the value is 1, the ticket is open and if the value is 0, the ticket is closed.

When I fill this dataGridView with the dataset that is brought in from the database, the Status column (the data from the ticket_status column) contains only 1's or 0's (as this is what they are stored as in the database)

I am wanting to process **only** this column before I assign the dataset as the data source for the dataGridView so that if the value of ticket_status is 1, the string "Open" is added to the column instead of 1 and if the value of ticket_status is 0, the string "Closed" is added to the column instead of 0.

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
ticket_status AS `Status`
```

with

```
IF(ticket_status=1,'Open','Closed') AS `Status`
```

inside your select statement